# Misaligned dots in ggplot2's dotplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't understand why the dots for ID 2,6,8,10 won't align vertically like they do in 1,3,4,7,9.

The offset is affected by stackratio, but why doesn't it affect all the groups?

```
ggplot(sleep, 
       aes(x=ID,fill=group,y=extra))+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y',
               method="histodot",
               stackgroups = TRUE,
               binpositions="bygroup",
               stackratio=1,
               binwidth=0.1, 
               stackdir = "center",
               dotsize = 3)
```

[image: plot]

Another example is

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(am),fill = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y",stackgroups = TRUE, stackdir = "center", binpositions="all")
```

Here `stackgroups = TRUE` makes everything offset weirdly.

[image: img]

Can something be done here, or is there another way to get the samme?

Comment: Try adjusting `binwidth=0.1` to smaller numbers. I believe this controls when the dots are considered to share a bin with another dot, and therefore offset.

Comment: Have tried that. This makes "grid" smaller, but since dot size is based on this, it also makes the dots smaller. To compensate, dot size can be increased by the same factor. When this is done, I get the same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that geom_dotplot calculates "dodge" positions as if all the dots were in one group and then plots them in each group.

I found work around. 
Here i make a plot and color the dots myself. This ggplot can not make a legend for, so I make another plot that was the right legend.
Then use plot_grid to make my final plot. 
It is important to setkey right, or the plot will be colored incorrect.

```
mycars <- as.data.table(mtcars)
mycars[cyl=="4",mycol:="red"][cyl=="6",mycol:="green"][cyl=="8",mycol:="blue"]
setkey(mycars,am,mpg)
myplot <- ggplot(mycars, aes(x = factor(am), y = mpg)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y",
               fill=mycars$mycol,
               stackratio=1,
               binwidth=0.7, drop=FALSE,
               stackdir = "center",
               dotsize = 1)

lplot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(am),fill = factor(cyl), y = mpg))+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y",stackgroups = TRUE)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","green", "blue"))
mylegend <- get_legend(lplot)

plot_grid(myplot,mylegend,ncol=2,rel_widths =  c(6,1))
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8iz0.png)

Comment: Just make sure this is plotting what you want. For instance, if you run your code and then look at your data, you see that points 14 and 15 have the same height (y=mpg=19.2), but points 12 and 13 do not (18.1,and 18.7) yet they are being plotted at the same height (and this happens to other points as well, for example, points 23, 24, 25). If that's what you want, ok. But it might give the misleading idea that points 12 and 13 have the exact same mpg.

Comment: That is a problem. This happens due to binwidth. I could decrease it by a factor 7 to 0.1 and increase dotsize by a factor 7. This would make place them side by side only if they are the same (since precision here is 1 digit)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you what's the issue when using the `geom_dotplot` function, but you can get what you want by using geom_point and the option `position = position_dodge2()`. Inside the function `position_dodge2()` you can use `width` to control the position of each point. See the full code below:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(sleep, 
       aes(x=ID,fill=group,y=extra))+
  geom_point(
    size=3,
    pch = 21,
    position = position_dodge2(width=c(rep(0.00001,4),
                                       0.2,
                                       rep(0.00001,5)))
  ) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-2,6)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color="gray",
                                          linetype = "dashed"))
```

The result:

[image]

---

## Update

We can have different alignments within the same X. For instance, when ID=1 I can move the point for group 2 while maintaining the point for group 1:

[image]

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(sleep, 
       aes(x=ID,fill=group,y=extra))+
  geom_point(
    size=3,
    pch = 21,
    position = position_dodge2(width=c(0.7,
                                       rep(0.00001,3),
                                       0.2,
                                       rep(0.00001,5),
                                       0.00001,
                                       rep(0.00001,3),
                                       0.2,
                                       rep(0.00001,5)))
  ) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-2,6)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color="gray",
                                          linetype = "dashed"))
```

Comment: This will work if all within the same X value has to be dodged, but for my other example this won't work. I did find a solution that I posted.

Comment: That's not quite correct. Like I said, if you use position_dodge2 you control the position of each point. However, it might take you a lot of time to understand how to move each point individually. Regarding your solution, take a look at my comment there.

Comment: I've updated my answer to account for this case. @Peter

Comment: I like the look for your graph better, but as you said yourself, it will take a lot of time when I have many points and a lot of plots.